# build insert statement error Https has already been declared

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-insert

I have a method which takes multiple images from the UI and stores them in the cache, when this has finished it calls a method which then references the cache pulls the images out and then passes them to the database, at the moment this insert statement is currently doing one at time, so it could be 7 hits to the database for one user.

What I'm tying to achieve is something like this, in SQL you would do  (multiple items inserted in to the database at once)

```
insert into table1 (First,Last) 
values 
     ('Fred','Smith'),
     ('John','Smith'),
     ('Michael','Smith'),
     ('Robert','Smith');
```

my code currently looks like this

```
public void SaveImages(List<Images> Images, Int64 userId)
{
  var extension = Images.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, item) => current + string.Format("({0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}),", userId, item.ImageName, item.ImageUrl, 1, DateTime.Now, null));
}
```

which once finished extension looks like this

```
(1253,xkvkvy4ldmfbhlmftqsc,https://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1423309462/rfefef.jpg,1,07/02/2015 11:45:29,),
(1253,pa0niomwvyzl47qjlxna,https://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1423309471/iuytre.jpg,1,07/02/2015 11:45:29,),
(1253,mymvektwddgco9nvbaap,https://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1423309479/sdfgh.jpg,1,07/02/2015 11:45:29,),
(1253,fxlftcx9jgrs9c7sjnv4,https://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1423309489/98iuiu.jpg,1,07/02/2015 11:45:29,),
```

And I call the insert statement and pass in extension

```
var query = @"
           INSERT INTO [User].Images
                  (UserId, FileName, ImageUrl, Active, CreatedDate, DeletedDate)

            VALUES
                  " + extension;

sqlCon.Query(query);
```

but it fails due to the following reason

```
The label 'https' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
```

I have googled this error, but I didn't receive any good solutions hence why I am asking here.

Comment: First, what ORM are you using? `Query` isn't part of EF, NH or Linq to SQL. Second, the issue is that you used string concatenation instead of a parameterized query or your ORM's insertion methods. No matter how much you escape, you'll always run into trouble when you create sql statements like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try putting the url (and other string values) between quotes:

```
(1253,'xkvkvy4ldmfbhlmftqsc','https://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1423309462/rfefef.jpg',1,07/02/2015 11:45:29,)
```

Comment: That seemed to work but it gives me another error which is 

Incorrect syntax near '12'. but I can't find '12.' in the examples I have provided

Comment: Put the date in quotes as well, and also provide the last column (with 'NULL' if thats your intention): `1253,'xkvkvy4ldmfbhlmftqsc','https://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1423309462/rfefef.jpg',1,'07/02/2015 11:45:29','NULL'`

Comment: done exactly as you have suggested and now I get Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: what is the value of `extension`?

Comment: The same as mentioned above, difference is it has single quotes around the url, name, date and null

Comment: How would I do that as I'm currently using linq to create the bulk insert

Comment: Select a format for every item and then join them with ',': `var formattedItems = Images.Select(i => string.format("({0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5})", ......)); var extension = string.Join(",", formattedItems);`

Comment: The only way to avoid such errors is to use a parameterized query. No matter how many escape quotes one uses, string concatenation will always fail for one reason or another *and* result in completely unreadable code