# Issue converting varchar to datetime in bulk insert statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datetime

This was working perfectly fine, until just now.  I haven't changed any code what so ever.

Ok so what the code below does is uses linq a constructs a bulk insert statement similar to how you would do it in SQL like this

```
insert into table1 (First,Last) 
values 
 ('Fred','Smith'),
 ('John','Smith'),
 ('Michael','Smith'),
 ('Robert','Smith');
```

My code userImages is a list of images

```
// build the bulk insert statement.
var tempStatement = userImages.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, item) => current + string.Format("({0},'{1}','{2}',{3},'{4}',{5}),", userId, item.ImageName, item.ImageUrl, 1, DateTime.Now, "NULL"));

// We now need to trim the last comma off the end, other wise we will get a syntax error in sql.
var extension = tempStatement.Substring(0, tempStatement.Length - 1);

using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(Con.ReturnDatabaseConnection()))
{
   var query = @"
                INSERT INTO [User].Images

                (UserId, FileName, ImageUrl, Active, CreatedDate, DeletedDate)

                VALUES
                      " + extension;

  sqlCon.Query(query);
}
```

When I put a break point on the using statement and look at var extension this is what is produced

```
(1247,'o7maxqx3w3yvjtgjivpq','https://res.location.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/v1424071993/o7maxqx3w3yvjtgjivpq.png',1,'16/02/2015 07:33:28',NULL)
```

but it errors converting varchar to datetime

This was working perfectly fine, so I'm unsure on how to proceed, I did ask for help setting this up as a question was raised here

[Bulk Insert statement, Look at the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381982/build-insert-statement-error-https-has-already-been-declared)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You aren't using LINQ anywhere. What ORM or micro-ORM are you using?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sorry I'm using Dapper.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the SQL statement is a plain INSERT, not a BULK INSERT. A BULK INSERT is used to load data from a file into the database as quickly as possible. This code just tries to add a single value.

Second, you are using string concatenation to pass the values, resulting in unexpected conversions of decimal and date values, not to mention exposing your code to SQL injection attacks. This also harms performance as the server has to recompile the statement each time.

You should use parameterized queries to avoid conversions altogether, improve performance *and* avoid injection attacks.

You don't mention what ORM you are using (LINQ is the query language, not the execution functions), but this is how you could write a parameterized query with plain ADO.NET:

```
var sql="INSERT INTO [User].Images (UserId, FileName, ImageUrl, Active, CreatedDate, DeletedDate) " + 
        "VALUES (@userid,@file,@image,@active,@created,@deleted)";
var sqlCmd=new SqlCommand(sqlCon,sql);
sqlCmd.AddWithValue("@userid",userId);
sqlCmd.AddWithValue("@filename",imageName);
sqlCmd.AddWithValue("@active",1);
sqlCmd.AddWithValue("@created",DateTime.Now);
sqlCmd.AddWithValue("@deleted",DBNull.Value);

sqlCon.Open();
sqlCmd.ExecuteNonScalar();
```

It's even easier to do this with an ORM, as the ORM will generate the parameterized query when you save the new object. You simply create the new object with the new values and save it using your ORM's persistence methods.

In Dapper.NET, the equivalent is:

```
var sql="INSERT INTO [User].Images (UserId, FileName, ImageUrl, Active, CreatedDate, DeletedDate) " + 
        "VALUES (@userid,@file,@image,@active,@created,@deleted)";
sqlCon.Execute(sql,new {
    userid=userId,
    filename=imageName,
    active=1,
    created=DateTime.Now,
    deleted=null
});
```

Dapper.NET can handle multiple items at once. Assuming you have a List of the DTOs, you could execute:

```
var sql="INSERT INTO [User].Images (UserId, FileName, ImageUrl, Active, CreatedDate, DeletedDate) " + 
        "VALUES (@userid,@file,@image,@active,@created,@deleted)";
sqlCon.Execute(sql,myListOfDTOs);
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm using Dapper.Net, what you have shown above is fine, but when I have ten images to insert I don't want to call the database ten times just to insert some records, Ideally I want to do it all at once

Comment: Updated for Dapper.NET. 10 records isn't much. To reduce the number of round-trips you need batching, not BULK operations. If you really want to do bulk inserts (ie you have hundreds or thousands of rows) you should use the [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class

Comment: The comment doesn't make much sense unless you are doing something completely different from the question or title - using a multi-valued insert. Anyway, you can pass a list of objects to Dapper, not just a single object

Comment: It does make sense, I was saying thanks for the information you provided me which I'm looking in to now.